# PostgreSQL to XML with 3 Tables

Tags: php, sql, xml, database, postgresql

I'm a trainee in a small dev team and my project leader wants me to write a function that will export PostgreSQL data to a XML file. Unfortunately, I only know how to write an export to a csv.

There are 3 different Tables and he wants it like this (XML view)

```
<Table 1 Col1=".." Col2="..">
    <Table 2 Col1="...">
        <Table3 Col1=".." Col2="" Col3=".." Col4="..." />
        <Table3 Col1=".." Col2="" Col3=".." Col4="..." />
        <Table3 Col1=".." Col2="" Col3=".." Col4="..." />       
     </Table2>
    <Table1>
        <Table1>....</Table>
    </Table>
</Table2>
<Table1 Col1="xxx" Col2="xxx">
 ...
```

The tags are each for my table names. How do I write the code to export this?

Other questions on StackOverflow are mainly focused on exporting a single table, so I hope that this question will also help others trying to export multiple tables.

Comment: I guess you're going to get familiar with PHP's [`XMLWriter`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three levels of nested tables.

### Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
  a_id integer primary key,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE b(
  b_id integer primary key,
  a_id integer references a(a_id),
  val text
);

CREATE TABLE c(
  c_id serial primary key,
  b_id integer references b(b_id),
  blah text
);

INSERT INTO a(a_id, name) VALUES (1, 'fred'),(2, 'bert');

INSERT INTO b(b_id, a_id, val) VALUES 
(11, 1, 'x'), (12, 1, 'y'), (21, 2, 'a'), (22, 2, 'b');

INSERT INTO c(b_id, blah) VALUES
(11, 'whatever'), (11, 'gah'), (12, 'borkbork'), (22, 'fuzz');
```

### Method 1: Do a left join, handle XML in the client

The simplest way to handle this is to do a left join over all three tables, ordered from outermost to innermost. Then you iterate down the result set, closing one element and opening another whenever the subject at that level changes.

```
select *
from a left join b on (a.a_id = b.a_id)
       left join c on (b.b_id = c.b_id)
order by a.a_id, b.b_id, c.c_id;
```

then loop over the rows returned, and for each row, **pseudocode**:

```
cur_row = get_new_row()

if (cur_row[b_id] != prev_row[b_id]) {
   emit_close_tableb();
}
if (cur_row[a_id] != prev_row[a_id]) {
   emit_close_tablea();
   emit_open_tablea(cur_row);
}
if (cur_row[b_id] != prev_row[b_id]) {
   emit_open_tableb(cur_row);
}
emit_tablec(cur_row);

prev_row = cur_row;
```

To write the XML you'd use something like [`XMLWriter`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php). To read the query data you can use something like PDO or whatever driver you prefer. If the data set is large consider using a cursor to read the data.

This works well, but it transfers a *lot* of excess data, since you transfer `n` copies of the outer table's data for each `n` rows of the inner table associated with it.

---

To reduce the excess data exchanged you can select only the IDs for the outer tables

```
select a.a_id, b.b_id, c.*
from a left join b on (a.a_id = b.a_id)
       left join c on (b.b_id = c.b_id)
order by a.a_id, b.b_id, c.c_id;
```

... then when you switch to a new tablea / tableb, `SELECT` the rest of its rows then. You'll probably use a second connection to do this so you don't distrupt the result set and cursor state on the main connection you're reading rows from.

### Method 2: Do it all in PostgreSQL

For smaller data sets, or for the inner levels of bigger data sets, you can use PostgreSQL's XML support to construct the XML documents, e.g.:

```
WITH xmlinput AS (
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
  LEFT JOIN c on (b.b_id = c.b_id)
  ORDER BY a.a_id, b.b_id, c.c_id
)
SELECT
  XMLELEMENT(name items,
    xmlagg(
      XMLELEMENT(name a,
        XMLFOREST((a).a_id AS a_id, (a)."name" AS name),
        b_xml
      )
    ORDER BY (a).a_id)
  ) AS output
FROM
(
  SELECT
    a,
    xmlagg(
      XMLELEMENT(name b,
        XMLFOREST((b).b_id AS b_id, (b).val AS val),
        c_xml
      )
    ORDER BY (b).b_id)
    AS b_xml
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      a, b,
      xmlagg(
        XMLELEMENT(name c,
          XMLFOREST((c).c_id AS c_id, (c).blah AS blah)
        )
      ORDER BY (c).c_id)
      AS c_xml
    FROM xmlinput
    GROUP BY a, b
  ) c_as_xml
  GROUP BY a
) b_as_xml;
```

... but really, you've got to be some kind of masochist to write code like that. Though it could prove to be fairly fast.

To understand the query [you'll need to read the PostgreSQL XML docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html). The wackly syntax was dreamed up by the SQL/XML committee, don't blame us.

Also note that *row-variables* are used heavily in the above code to keep it organized. `a`, `b` and `c` are passed as whole rows to outer layers of the query. This avoids the need to mess with aliases when names collide. The syntax `(a).a_id`, etc, means "the `a_id` field of the row-variable `a`". See the PostgreSQL manual for details.

The above uses a better XML structure (see comments below). If you want to emit attributes not elements, you can change the `XMLFOREST` calls to `XMLATTRIBUTES` calls.

Output:

```
<items><a><a_id>1</a_id><name>fred</name><b><b_id>11</b_id><val>x</val><c><c_id>1</c_id><blah>whatever</blah></c><c><c_id>2</c_id><blah>gah</blah></c></b><b><b_id>12</b_id><val>y</val><c><c_id>3</c_id><blah>borkbork</blah></c></b></a><a><a_id>2</a_id><name>bert</name><b><b_id>21</b_id><val>a</val><c/></b><b><b_id>22</b_id><val>b</val><c><c_id>4</c_id><blah>fuzz</blah></c></b></a></items>
```

or, pretty-printed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<items>
    <a>
        <a_id>1</a_id>
        <name>fred</name>
        <b>
            <b_id>11</b_id>
            <val>x</val>
            <c>
                <c_id>1</c_id>
                <blah>whatever</blah>
            </c>
            <c>
                <c_id>2</c_id>
                <blah>gah</blah>
            </c>
        </b>
        <b>
            <b_id>12</b_id>
            <val>y</val>
            <c>
                <c_id>3</c_id>
                <blah>borkbork</blah>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <a_id>2</a_id>
        <name>bert</name>
        <b>
            <b_id>21</b_id>
            <val>a</val>
            <c />
        </b>
        <b>
            <b_id>22</b_id>
            <val>b</val>
            <c>
                <c_id>4</c_id>
                <blah>fuzz</blah>
            </c>
        </b>
    </a>
</items>
```

### Please emit better XML

On a side note, using attributes like that in XML seems tempting, but it quickly gets difficult and ugly to work with. Please just use normal XML elements:

```
  <Table 1>
    <Nr>1</Nr>
    <Name>blah</Name>
     <Table 2>
       <Nr>1</Nr>
       <Table 3>
          <Col1>42</Col1>
          <Col2>...</Col2>
          <Col3>...</Col3>
          <Col4>...</Col4>
          ...
       </Table 3>
     </Table 2>
   </Table 1>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is a bit confusing. I will try this out but if you have a bit Spare time could you try to show me a Sample unsing my variables?

Comment: @sguetsch In the above, I  `tablea` = `Konzern`, `tableb` = `HSN`, `tablec` = `TSN`, if I've understood your example correctly. The point is to use a series of left joins with results ordered from outermost to innermost table and iterate over the result set, opening and closing tags when something changes between rows.

Comment: @sguetsch BTW, if the data is fairly small you can do this entirely within PostgreSQL, using just SQL. For me to show you any kind of useful example of that you'd have to actually provide some usable data as a http://sqlfiddle.com/ or similar, though.

Comment: Yep, you've understood it right :) Thank you for your help *thumbs up*

Comment: @sguetsch I've added an example of how to generate the XML using only a PostgreSQL query, too. Though you'll want to be pretty comfortable with SQL if you take that approach.

Comment: Btw; as you said "fairly small"; The file that should be exported would have 1179 Pages, 394.780 Words and 3.958.291 characters :D

Comment: But I'd like to thank you for your work again, It helped me a lot and I hope some StackO users in the future, too

Comment: @sguetsch That doesn't sound hugely big. Worth a go in SQL if you feel like enduring the syntax. It's not *that* bad. BTW, out of interest, are you working with Scribus? Something about this makes me think of its document format. Unfortunately.

Comment: Nope, LibreOffice. But damn, it's really hard. I mean, I got my Abitur (I think it's called A-Level in some englishspeaking regions) about 2 months ago and never woked with PHP, applied as Java Dev and now.. :D So, any kind of help is warmly welcome

Comment: @sguetsch PHP is more survivable if you try to always look for the new-new-new way of doing things. `pg_query`? Nope, use PDO. XML? Don't use the DOM, use XMLWriter. etc. This means ignoring lots and *lots* of bad, outdated advice and tutorials and examples. Including quite a bit in the manual. There are some decent documents with guidance on writing sensible PHP5 that can be useful.

Comment: somehow i have problems with this part  ` cur_row = get_new_row()`
is this a function or how should I use this? In my understanding your code does workl like $row ++, doesn't it? 
Aw, damn, I have so many questions :/ Sorry

Comment: @sguetsch [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) refers to text structured like code that uses programming conventions to illustrate a concept, without focusing on the libraries and syntax of a particular programming language. In other words, it's a way to *describe* what to do. You will need to use your PHP database driver and query tools to execute a query and then loop over the rows fetched. See, e.g. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Is there a chance that you can send me the XMLWriter code that u have used? Because It seems that mine i a bit..wrong

Comment: @sguetsch I didn't write code for this specific case, except for the PostgreSQL query shown above. I have *explained* how to do it, but not written the code step-by-step. That part is up to you. If you continue to try and get stuck, you should probably post a new question with the [tag:php] [tag:xml] [tag:xmlwriter] tags, containing a *self-contained example* (i.e. one that doesn't rely on your database contents; maybe hard-code an array of rows into the example). You could also read the XMLWriter documentation and look up examples, or ask your PL for help since he insists on PHP.

Comment: @sguetsch One tip: if you're having problems, simplify and separate. Check to make sure the DB query part of your code works and produces the expected rows. Separately, check that the XML writer part of your code works on dummy input. Narrow down the problem that way.

Comment: Just a nearly off topic question. Is it Possible to Import this file?

Comment: @sguetsch Please post a new question for a new topic. It's fine (and recommended) to link to this one for context and back-story.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092750/import-xml-file-into-postgresql-database]